# How to access multiple return values from solidity function in web3.js

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript, nodejs

I have written a solidity contract deployed on Ropsten network. I am using lite-server, NodeJS to develop a front-end. I have figured out how to use events and I can access a getter with one return value:

```
 myBorrower.getBorrowerName(function(err, res) {
    $("#loader").show();
    if (!err) {
        $("#borrower").html('Borrower Name: ' + web3.toAscii(res));
        $("#loader").hide();
    }
});
```

but I cannot figure out how to access a getter with 2 values in the callback function in web3. The Javascript code is:

```
   myPortfolio.getPortfolioInfo(function(err, res) {
        $("#loader").show();
        if (!err) {
            $("#portfolio").html('Portfolio Name: ' + web3.toAscii(value.args[0]) + ' Ether Balance: ' + web3.toAscii(value.args[1]));
            $("#loader").hide();
        }
    });
```

I know that `args[0]` is not correct, but I cannot figure out what it should be.

The relevant solidity function is:

```
    function getPortfolioInfo() public view returns (bytes16, uint){

    return (portfolioName, portfolioBalance);
}
```

Can anyone help me with this please? Thanks.

Comment: I think it's just `res[0]` and `res[1]`, but it should be easy to see by just doing `console.log(res)`, right?

Comment: You are right! Thanks. I had tried that before but it did not work. The reason though was that I applied web3.toAscii to both res[0] and res[1] but res[1] is a uint not bytes16 so cannot be converted to Ascii. When I use the following it works - $("#portfolio").html('Portfolio Name: ' + web3.toAscii(res[0]) + ' Balance: ' + res[1]);

Comment: I have one follow up question. if I return an array from getPortfolioInfo and I want to access it, how do I do so? Would it be res[0][0] where [0] is the first element in the array? Any idea how that could work?

Comment: This is a really simple thing to just try yourself.

Comment: I am sure it is really simple and I feel pretty silly. I cannot figure it out. Could you please help me though? I would really appreciate it. What I am trying is $("#loans").html('Loan ID: ' + web3.toAscii(res[4][0].loanID)); The fourth value passed is an array of addresses with a bytes16 loanID.

Comment: Just `console.log(res)` and look at it. If you still can't figure out how to get the data you want, share what `res` looks like (and maybe the current function that returns it).